# How do you set your NDK project to use arm7 and x86?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to set my project to be for both arm-v7 and intel x86. What would be the correct syntax for it? In my Application.mk file, I currently have

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

but I'm not sure what the syntax is for x86, and how to append.

Comment: space x86 space x86_64

Comment: all builds all flavours, it's slower tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax to use inside *Application.mk* is:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86
```

You can also set it to all to support all the platforms the NDK supports:

```
APP_ABI := all
```